# Importing limited number of tables using sqoop

Tags: sqoop

I have 100 tables in mysql and i just want to import just 10 tables using sqoop. can anyone help me how to import just 10 tables?

```
sqoop import --connect
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write 10 `sqoop import` commands for that.

[`sqoop import-all-tables`](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_import_all_tables_literal) can be used to import all the tables in a database and exclude few tables using

```
--exclude-tables <tables>
```

where `<tables>` is comma separated list of tables to exclude from import process.

Comment: in that case do i have to mention remaining 90 tables in my import statement. Is there any other way

Comment: @sharath no other way as far as I know